# Can native CiviContribute capture In-Kind donations?

Tags: civicontribute

We are new to Civi. We need a mechanism to capture In-Kind contributions from our contacts e.g furniture, toys, services, books. I cannot see how native Civicontribute allows this and the help doc doesn't give specifics or ways to configure the contribute screen for non-financial data? Help please!!

Answer (score 6):

Civi is pretty flexible.

First, click Administer | CiviContribute | Financial Types. Then add a new financial type and name it "In-Kind".

You can also create custom fields that will appear on the contribution form. Click Administer | Custom Data and Screens | Custom Fields.
Click Add Set of Custom Fields, and create a custom field set to hold your custom fields, then continue to add any number of custom fields such as Description (a Note field), Qty (an Integer Text field), etc. You can add drop-downs or multi-selects to categorize donations. You can even choose to make your custom fields searchable.